# Asking a question about benefits of being a good programmer who also has a degree on electrical engineering

Tags: discussion, site-rec

I am confused on what SE sites should I ask that question, should I ask this here or in electrical engineering SE? It seems that this question is not fit on both sites.

Right now I am in the field of programming (client - server using serial and tcp/ip) with a degree of information technology and due to certain events I am obligated to study electrical engineering course. I am thinking about the benefits of having a good programming background if I go to the field of electrical engineering.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

The answer to what the possible benefits are for someone who has a degree in ${something} and ${something else} is both too broad (there are too many possible answers that can be given) and primarily opinion (what someone considers a benefit in one case may not be a benefit in another).

Since too broad and primarily opinion span all stack exchange sites as close reasons, it is not a good question for any of them.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is clear to me now.